# How to escape unbalanced brackets or slash in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, quoting

I'm trying to use `sed`, but my pattern contains `[]` brackets and slashes (`/`).

I've tried quotes, but it doesn't help.

How do I escape it?

---

Examples:

```
$ sed -i'.bak' "s/^includes[] =/;includes[] =/g" *.make
sed: 1: "s/^includes[] =/;includ ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
$ sed -i'.bak' 's/^includes[] = includes/;includes/g' *.make
sed: 1: "s@^includes[] = i ...": unbalanced brackets ([])
$ sed -i'.bak' 's/^includes[] = foo/includes//;includes[] = foo/includes//g' *.make
sed: 1: "s/^includes[] = foo/inc ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

Comment: For your particular example, it seems you want to add a semicolon to the beginning of every line starting with `includes`. You can just do `sed 's/^includes/;&/' your_file` where `&` is what was matched by the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape slashes, you can use any character other than a forward slash to separate regular expressions.

E.g. (`foo1/` -> `foo2/`):

```
sed "s@foo1/@foo2/@"
sed "s|foo1/|foo2/|"
```

To escape brackets (this work also for slashes) you've to put a backslash character before the delimiting character causes the character to be treated literally.

E.g. (`foo[] =` -> `;foo[] =`):

```
sed "s/foo\[\] =/;foo\[\] =/"
```

Read more by running `man sed` (*Sed Regular Expressions*).